# Enforce 32-bit enums with GCC linker

Tags: c, gcc, enums, arm, ld

I'm writing a bare metal application for an ARM device (no OS). I need 32-bit enums, so I compiled the application with the `-fno-short-enums` compiler flag. Without this flag, I get variable enums (and enforcing the size by adding an additional `0xFFFFFFFF` value to each enum is not an option).

Now I get the following linker warning for every object:

```
c:/gcc-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: ./src/test.o uses 32-bit enums yet the output is to use variable-size enums; use of enum values across objects may fail
```

It's just a warning, no error. But what does it mean exactly? How can I specify the "output"?

I tried to recompile the newlib with the above flag to ensure that all objects use the same enum size, but I'm still getting the warning. Is there something I missed?

Comment: Why do you need 32-bit enums?

Comment: Maybe you should add some flags to linker, and use short enums for all objects.

Comment: I need it for compatibility to software parts on other platforms/processors. I definitely need 32-bit enums.

Comment: What kind of compatibility? Networking?

Comment: Btw, don't you use some other libraries? Show the full build log :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a while I got it working.
I rebuilt the whole toolchain including the compiler with this flag. Here is the way I did:

1. Get the toolchain **source** from https://developer.arm.com/open-source/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm/downloads
2. Add 3 lines to some sections of the buildscript `build-toolchain.sh`:

   ```
   saveenv
   saveenvvar CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET '-fno-short-enums'
     [...build commands...]
   restoreenv
   ```

   Modified sections:

   - `Task [III-1] /$HOST_NATIVE/gcc-first/`
   - `Task [III-2] /$HOST_NATIVE/newlib/`
   - `Task [III-4] /$HOST_NATIVE/gcc-final/`
   - `Task [IV-3] /$HOST_MINGW/gcc-final/`

   I Skipped building `newlib-nano` and `gcc-size-libstdcxx`.
3. Run the modified Scripts `build-prerequisites.sh` and `build-toolchain.sh` to build everything.

---

After that, the compiler is using the large-enum-mode and the linker is fine with my objects. But now, I get the opposit warning for some objects of the newlib (`lib_a-mbtowc_r.o`, `lib_a-svfiprintf.o`, `lib_a-svfprintf.o`, `lib_a-vfprintf.o` and `lib_a-vfiprintf.o`):

```
c:/gcc-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: c:/gcc-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libc.a(lib_a-mbtowc_r.o) uses variable-size enums yet the output is to use 32-bit enums; use of enum values across objects may fail
```

I looked into the makefiles of these object and they are explicitly set to variable-size-enums, sadly. The only "solution" for this, was to add a linker flag to mute this warning:

```
-Xlinker -no-enum-size-warning
```

That's it.

Comment: Should be `-Xlinker` (With the lowercase `l`).
`arm-none-eabi-g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-XLinker'; did you mean '-Xlinker'?`

Comment: Alternative syntax (in gcc) is `-Wl,-no-enum-size-warning`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem since I have a lot of enums in data structures that map to hardware. In my case, my fix is to do the following:

```
struct x {
  union {
      enum my_enum eval;
      uint32_t :32;
  };
  uint32_t some_val;
  ...
}
```

This works and is transparent outside of the data structure, though it means that every time an enum is used in a data structure this union wrapper is required.  I suppose a macro might be possible as well. I agree it's a pain. Every other 32-bit and 64-bit environment I've worked with treats enums as 32-bits and don't get me started with the decision to make a uint32_t an unsigned long in the ARM embedded ABI (every other one I've worked with it's an unsigned int, making portability with 64-bit ABIs easy).

Answer (score -1):

I have a partial answer as I had the same question.  The problem is a warning message from the linker that will appear with the use of -fno-short-enums.  The message indicates that the target object is not compatible.  So I spent a world of time looking for now to change the target to be compatible.

But that wasn't the problem.  The gcc compiler will build 32-bit enums by default!!  So this option is no necessary unless you DONT want 32-bit enums.  However, if you do specify the -fno-short-enums you will receive the warning message.  Unfortunately I don't know why.

So the bottom line is that the no-short-enums flag is not necessary to achieve 32-bit enums.  If you do specify it then you will receive the warning message.

Comment: No, on ARM, gcc will use by default the smallest enum size depending on the values to store. Check _4.9 Structures, Unions, Enumerations, and Bit-Fields_ in gcc doc.

Comment: @calandoa Yes, but if (based on the value) 32-bit enums are needed, then the Enum will be 32-bit. That's the point. The flag forces ALL enums to be X size rather than letting them be whatever size is necessary. You would only want that if you want a fixed size regardless of the values for whatever reason.

Comment: This answer is saying "The gcc compiler will build 32-bit enums by default!". This statement is false for the target specified by the question. Therefore the answer is false. I do not understand why you are seeing a point somewhere else.